# Grep only string in a line in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I writing a shell script.
The line will look like:

```
"holderIdentity":"leader-elector1-5cd5b9d76d-ztfgf","numberofLeader":{"":0,"node2":1,"node3":2,"node4":2}"
```

The character `5cd5b9d76d-ztfgf` will be created randomly, so my keyword to grep is just only `leader-elector`. And the string `,"numberofLeader":{"":0,"node2":1,"node3":2,"node4":2}"` is also randomly (it is diffent everytime)

How can I get just this string `leader-elector1-5cd5b9d76d-ztfgf` from the line.

Thank you so much!

Comment: `grep -Eo 'leader-elector[^"]*' <<< '"holderIdentity":"leader-elector1-5cd5b9d76d-ztfgf","numberofLeader":{"":0,"node2
":1,"node3":2,"node4":2}"'`

Comment: Don't forget to show your attempt.

Comment: Are you dealing with JSON? Use `jq`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using GNU grep

```
grep -Eo 'leader-elector[^"]*' <<< '"holderIdentity":"leader-elector1-5cd5b9d76d-ztfgf","numberofLeader":{"":0,"node2 ":1,"node3":2,"node4":2}"'
```

otherwise with bash regex feature

```
var='"holderIdentity":"leader-elector1-5cd5b9d76d-ztfgf","numberofLeader":{"":0,"node2 ":1,"node3":2,"node4":2}"'
re='leader-elector[^"]*'

if [[ $var =~ $re ]] ; then
  declare -p BASH_REMATCH
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried `grep -Eo 'leader-elector[^"]*'`, it worked